# Regular Expression "a{2}" not working

Tags: sql, regex, database

I have a record with emp_name = "Rajat" and it is not getting returned.

My query is -

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_name regexp "a{2}"
```

Please explain why it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex search for `aa`

https://www.regex101.com/r/yA1qA2/1

What you need is:

```
 a.*a
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/hA5yS8/1

Answer (score 0):

`a{2}` means two consecutive `a`s. Your string doesn't match it.

To match a string with two `a` characters that might not be consecutive characters you should use `a.*a`.

Answer (score 0):

`a{2}` will match two straight `a` characters, i.e.: `aa`.
To match 2 alternate `a` characters you can use:

```
select * from employees where emp_name REGEXP "^.*a.*a.*$";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is [`LIKE` with `%`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> `LIKE` - Simple pattern matching
>
> **Character  Description** 
>   `%`             Matches any number of characters, even zero
>   characters
>   `_`             Matches exactly one character
>
> `LIKE` pattern match... succeeds only if the pattern matches the entire value

So, you can use a more specific

```
select * from employees where emp_name like '%a_a%';
```

Or, a more "generic" (allowing more characters than 1 between `a` and `a`:

```
select * from employees where emp_name like '%a%a%';
```

However, since in MySQL, *SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default*, so, you might have to use `REGEXP` with `BINARY` to [narrow down your search results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/pattern-matching.html):

> Prior to MySQL 3.23.4, REGEXP is case sensitive.
>
> From MySQL 3.23.4 on, if you really want to force a REGEXP comparison
>   to be case sensitive, use the BINARY keyword to make one of the
>   strings a binary string.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_name REGEXP BINARY 'a.*a';
```

Comment: Thanks stribizhev, Thanks for the help